# What is the interrelationship among PD, T1 and T2 in relation to MRI

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics

Proton Density (PD), Spin - Lattice Relaxation Time (T1), Spin - Spin Relaxation Time (T2) are three major characteristics by which we can distinguish different types of tissues and all three are intrinsic properties of a tissue.

Therefore, can we have a mathematical relationship (applicable to any type of tissue) to find T1 and T2 as functions of PD only?

Answer (score 1):

If T2 and T1 could be computed with a mathematical relationship as function of PD only, T2/T1/PD-weighted images would have exactly the same contrast and they would give us the same information, as tissues with the same PD will necessarily have the same value of T2 and T1.

T1 and T2 depends on many parameters!